# 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. [Sphinx]

Tags: python-sphinx

I was trying to study sphinx python documentation, i was struggling to make an html inside of my directory. I already try it to my cmd prompt but the error shows.

$ make html

P.s I already install Python and NodeJs and Git (incase)

Comment: Have you installed `make`?

Comment: choco install make ??

Comment: sphinx-quickstart creates a `make.bat` file. It should work if you are on Windows.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @StevePiercy: The error message is the title of the question.

Comment: @mzjn , I have the make.bat file

Comment: Is the directory where make.bat is located the working directory when you execute "make html"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my own answer on my own question.
You should locate your own directory and make sure you sphinx-build in your folder